# Splitting files into folders

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Would someone please get me started with Automator and/or AppleScript.  I've gotten more than a little frustrated with it.  I'd like to take a very large folder of files (thousands), in a predetermined order (perhaps by name or by date) and move them into subfolders, each of which is no more than a specified size (probably 4.7GB).  I don't want ISOs or DMGs or anything just my files nicely split into disk size chunks.  No reshuffling of the order either.  If a disk only fits a single 10MB file because the next one would blow the limit then so be it.  No file will be bigger than the limit either in case your wondering - they will be up to about 50MB tops.

So far I've got a Folder Action with Get Selected Finder Items followed by this AppleScript

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return first item of input
end run
```

That gets me the first item.  I can create a folder e.g. Disk 1 too.  And I can move the file also.  But how can I work out whether to move to this folder or if it's time for a new folder to be created?

I'd like to do this in Automator if possible, but suspect I'll need a little AppleScript.  I'm sure this problem has been solved already, so please just link me if you can.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes fair enough.  But I've got a plate full at the moment and was hoping someone might be able to spend a few minutes and give me the shell of something I can continue on with.

Comment: I'm a Windows man.  Macs aren't my forte.  I'm bad.

Comment: When you say Actionscript, do you actually mean Actionscript, or do you mean Applescript? Also, maybe command line/terminal is the way to go.

Comment: Yes I think I do mean AppleScript, sorry.

Comment: Would you say that I should use bash?

Comment: @MonkeyMan not sure what csh is. I know nothing about Mac sorry.

Comment: That is also my problem

Comment: You have started with the assumption that Automator or AppleScript is the solution. Automator does not provide the necessary controls. It could be done in AppleScript, but if you do not know AppleScript it is going to be difficult. You could do it with a shell script, but this requires advanced scripting. You would be better to write something in a language like Python. Better still search for existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a working AppleScript that will do this. It's imperfect but gets the job done.

It can be very slow with lots of files, I'm sure it can be improved though. High performance is not one of Applescript's strengths.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set files_folder to folder POSIX file "/Users/MonkeyMan/Desktop/MyMessOfFiles"
    set destination_folder to folder POSIX file "/Users/MonkeyMan/Desktop/SortedFiles"

    set target_size to 250.0 --   size limit your after in MB.

    set file_groupings to {} -- list we will store our stuff in
    set current_files to {} -- list of the current files we are adding size 

    set total_files to the count of files in files_folder

    set current_size_count to 0

    repeat with i from 1 to total_files
        set file_size to (the size of file i of files_folder) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 -- convert to MB to help prevent overrunning what the variable can hold

        if ((current_size_count + file_size) ≥ target_size) then
            -- this will overrun our size limit so store the current_files and reset the counters
            set the end of file_groupings to current_files
            set current_files to {}
            set current_size_count to 0
        end if

        set current_size_count to current_size_count + file_size
        set the end of current_files to (a reference to (file i of files_folder) as alias)

        if (i = total_files) then
            -- its the last file so add the current files disreagarding current size
            copy current_files to the end of file_groupings
        end if

    end repeat

    -- Copy the files into sub folders
    set total_groups to the count of file_groupings
    repeat with i from 1 to total_groups
        set current_group to item i of file_groupings
        set dest_folder to my ensureFolderExists(("disk " & i), destination_folder)
        move current_group to dest_folder
    end repeat

end tell

say "finished"

on ensureFolderExists(fold_name, host_folder)
    tell application "Finder"
        if not (exists folder fold_name of host_folder) then
            return make new folder at host_folder with properties {name:fold_name}
        else
            return folder fold_name of host_folder
        end if
    end tell
end ensureFolderExists
```